# Jupiter notebook doesn't find libraries from the virtual env

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, python-module, pyenv

I created a Pyenv virtual env. After activating the env, I download libraries like **pandas** into it. However, when I open a jupyter notebook from the same environment's terminal, pandas is not found there. It gives a module not found. I believe it's because the Jupiter notebook is using python from somewhere else while my other terminal was using python from somewhere else:

From my terminal, when I check `which python`, I get this:

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims/python
```

How can I ensure that my jupypter notebook is using the same env?

P.S I know I can separately install libraries again in the Jupiter notebook but that's not my qs

Comment: did my answer work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to click on "Kernel" in the  jupyter notebook bar (in the top). Next go to "Change Kernel" then select the venv you created

Edit:
ok I tried it myself

after you activate your venv make sure to ..

install jupyter within the venv:

```
pip install jupyter
```

then :

```
ipython kernel install --name "my-venv" --user
```

(or however you want to name it) -> this will add your virtualenvironment as kernel for jupyter

then run

```
jupyter-notebook
```

when inside the notebook click on "New" in top right corner, then choose the name you gave the kernel before ("my-venv") -> et vilà

Comment: I only see ```Python (ipykernel)``` as an option

Comment: so now this should do it :)